# Serial Differencing Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my 1st attempt at Elasticsearch. I am trying to sort the data based on timestamp and in the result I want the difference between 2 consecutive timestamps.

I am trying to achieve the same through Serial Differencing Aggregation where I expect a field output with the difference. I do not get any output field with the difference.

So the question is this approach correct or there is something else that needs to be done?

```
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ts"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_date_histo": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "ts",
            "interval": "second"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "the_sum": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "lemmings"
              }
            },
            "thirtieth_difference": {
              "serial_diff": {
                "buckets_path": "the_sum",
                "lag": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here I do not have a field named "lemmings" but ElasticSearch does not complain.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I assume if you don't have a `lemmings` field then it's not going to give you any results.

Comment: No, This one never worked. We did on the front end.